# Redirect user to another domain and get a final URL?

Tags: javascript, axios, frontend

I'm trying to create a small helper .html file for our team. The main purpose of this file is to fetch information automatically.

The full process will look like this:

1. Redirect user to another.domain.com/authorize?redirect_url=http://localhost?access_code=***
2. another.domain.com/authorize redirects the user back to the redirect URL with `auth_code` GET param
3. (Here I struggle) I need to access `auth_code` from the URL
4. I use auth_code to get information that is needed

Right now I don’t know how to approach step 3. Due to CORS, I can't use something like `axios.post`/`fetch` and then read the redirect URL. I also can't access the iframe URL due to cross-domain policy when I try to use one, even though in the end user is redirected to the same origin I'm trying to access the iframe from.

Sure, I can use a node.js server to handle this, but the idea is to have a simple .html file that can be opened on any OS without the need to install any dependencies. Is it possible to implement what I want?

Answer (score 0):

If i correctly understand then
more then javascript i would think about use server-side language like php for example to make curl to make call to api of external site then do redirect based on retrived data

Sorry if im wrong but i didn't heard about frontend calls between 2 domains that don't make CORS exception